# Solving a recurrence relation using generating functions - power series form of the partial fraction?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I wanted to solve a recurrence relation of the form

$$(a+2b+c)f_{n}=bf_{n+1}+bf_{n-1}+cf_{0}$$

I know how to get the solution using the characteristic equation method but I wanted to solve it using Generating functions method.
I have used $G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_{n}{x^n}$ as the generating function.
While proceeding for the solution, I reached till the partial fractions for the $G(x)$ and obtained

$$
G(x) = \frac{(\frac{cf_0}{a+c})}{1-x}
     + \frac{(\frac{bf_0}{a+c})(a+cx)}{bx^2-(a+2b+c)x+b}
$$

I know the first term has the power series form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ but I cannot figure out how to obtain the power series form for the second term so that I can get the general form of $f_n$.

Also, it is given that $f_m=1$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

Comment: You could factor the quadratic in the denominator and apply partial fractions again.

Comment: Thank you. This helped. I have got the final result that matched my previous result that I got from the characteristic equation method.